# Problem with request to asp.net and flutter in emulator debug

Tags: asp.net, flutter

I have a problem with my requests from my flutter application to my asp.net server, when I make a request to my server it does not go through, I have this message: Connection closed before full header was received . I deactivated all my firewalls, I used the url 10.0.0.2 + port of my server on the flutter side, on the backend side I did this for cors: [backend cors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT6ua.png) but it still doesn't work, I've been on this problem for 4 days, I've searched all over the web looking for a solution but I can't find anything. help me please

[host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy0ru.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: your host and device should be in same conenction